# How to parse this download link to get redirect URL?

Tags: php, parsing, curl, download, upload

if I have this url: https://p-ams2.pcloud.com/cfZef5XTZVizxYkZNTGjZZsikL67Z2ZZKYRZZrYP6e7ZgVZQZTVZ4XZN7Zw7ZfVZBkZgXZLVZokZJ7ZxZ1XZ6MJPDKvi9cQXwzvKARfMHfHsN5WX/SH-LMP-SS-JUN15.zip

Here is my codes:

```
<?php
$name="19875379";
$url = "https://p-ams2.pcloud.com/cfZef5XTZVizxYkZNTGjZZsikL67Z2ZZKYRZZrYP6e7ZgVZQZTVZ4XZN7Zw7ZfVZBkZgXZLVZokZJ7ZxZ1XZ6MJPDKvi9cQXwzvKARfMHfHsN5WX/SH-LMP-SS-JUN15.zip".$name;

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$header = curl_exec($ch);
$redir = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
//print_r($header);

$x = preg_match("/<script>location.href=(.|\n)*?<\/script>/", $header, $matches);
$script = $matches[0];
$redirect = str_replace("<script>location.href='", "", $script);
$redirect = "http://www.pcloud.com" . str_replace("';</script>", "", $redirect);

echo $redirect; 
?>
```

& Output is:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\58.php on line 18
http://www.pcloud.com
```

Am I doing any wrong in this php codes while parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://p-ams2.pcloud.com/cfZef5XTZVizxYkZNTGjZZsikL67Z2ZZKYRZZrYP6e7ZgVZQZTVZ4XZN7Zw7ZfVZBkZgXZLVZokZJ7ZxZ1XZ6MJPDKvi9cQXwzvKARfMHfHsN5WX/SH-LMP-SS-JUN15.zip
```

Link is broken. Maybe redirect is header location, not script tag?

or try it;

```
$ tevsi() { wget --server-response $1 2>&1 | grep "^Location"; } 
$ tevsi https://p-ams2.pcloud.com/cfZef5XTZVizxYkZNTGjZZsikL67Z2ZZKYRZZrYP6e7ZgVZQZTVZ4XZN7Zw7ZfVZBkZgXZLVZokZJ7ZxZ1XZ6MJPDKvi9cQXwzvKARfMHfHsN5WX/SH-LMP-SS-JUN15.zip
```

Comment: I am beginner of php codes, where to try your codes, I mean where to place your codes in my codes.

Comment: I think link already parse that is why it is impossible to find again.